# CONTAINS search

Tags: database, ms-access, search

Im trying to perform a CONTAINS search in Microsoft access, i am running a query that will contain all members whose email address comes from Google and yahoo. i can run the query that will return members whose address contains exact phrases such as Google.com, but as these members are world wide not all address are .com. so i am trying to return members whose address contains the words Google or yahoo.

Can some please tell me how to complete a free-text search in stead of an exact match? im trying to do this in a Microsoft access database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Email Like "*" & [Enter string to search for:] & "*"
```